# Склонение слова Случай

Tags: склонение

Как правильно: "в данном случае" или "в данном случаи"? Почему на проверочном сайте оба варианта верны?

Comment: Если вы говорите про какой-то проверочный сайт, то и вопрос надо туда адресовать. "А как верно" - это уже вопрос, к сайту отношения не имеющий.

Answer (score 2):

Единственно возможный вариант: "В данном случае". Это предложный падеж. В винительном было бы "в данный случай".

Во множественном числе: "в данные случаи" и "в данных случаях" соответственно.

"Проверочные сайты" не обсуждаю.